# NodeJS Передача значений переменных между файлами

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подскажите, как можно организовать в node js, что б значения переменной по ссылке скажем в файле
`big-list.js`

```
export let bigData = [
  'https://google.com',
  'https://habr.com/',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/',
];
```

было доступно в другом файле, скажем `server.js`

```
const bigList = require("big-list.js");
function getResult(){
    return console.log(bigList);
}
getResult();
```

Что не так в синтаксисе? Почему выдает ошибку `Cannot use import statement outside a module` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В nodejs по умолчанию экспортирование идет так:

`big-list.js`

```
module.exports = [
  'https://google.com',
  'https://habr.com/',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/',
];
```

`server.js`

```
const bigList = require("big-list.js");
console.log(bigList);
```

Но вы можете добавить в `package.json` опцию `"type": "module"`, чтобы использовать `import/export`:

`big-list.js`

```
export default [
  'https://google.com',
  'https://habr.com/',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/',
];
```

`server.js`

```
import bigList from "big-list.js";
console.log(bigList);
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/import-export

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. PS Во втором примере только при импорте путь `import bigList from "./big-list.js";`